# fader not fading?

Tags: audio, mixer

I have a small, inexpensive mixing board that has been through some moderate wear. The individual channels and various controls work, except that the master fader only affects the volume of the right channel. The left channel stays on at moderate volume regardless of the fader position (while the right varies as it should).

I opened it up and sprayed it with deoxit but no change, and I can't tell what on earth would be causing this. Any insights would be awesome!

Comment: broken solder joint on slider?

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean the joints where the slider is connected to the circuit board? (I checked those points and they look OK). Or is there something inside the slider that might be awry? (I can't really see in there).

Comment: then check if V out C changes with slider using a DMM or scope to see if problem is on input , output or inside of Pot.

Comment: A simple fader is a linear stereo pot where the top and bottom ends are swapped for one channel. That way, one channel gets more loud automatically when the other gets less loud and vice versa. If there's any electrical connection broken, that channel is simply stuck at either zero or full volume.

Comment: @Janka: the master fader on a mixer is a stereo control - both channels should fade up or down together.  You're thinking of a Pan or Balance control.

Comment: If the left channel is at moderate volume, not full on, I would suspect that the wiper (moving contact inside the pot) has become disconnected from the knob.

Comment: I thought of a crossfader, actually.

Comment: @PeterBennett That's what I thought! Tried to open up the slider to see and broke it in the process. Oh well -- thanks for the insights everyone.

Answer (score 1):

For mechanical linear pots, the two failure points will be the traces going to the pot, or internal damage. You can try testing in circuit, but its unlikely to show you any different. You could remove the fader and measure it there. Both sides of the fader should have similar resistance, but in opposite directions of the wiper.

Fancier digital mixers may have a digital pot or a circuit to measure the pots position, which then is used to adjust the output of a DAC or op amp section. In that cause it's much more complicated, and without more information and detailed testing from you, we cannot say.